# Why "idolatria" instead of "idololatria"?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, vulgata

Although the idea of idolatry has been present for a long time, I believe St. Paul is the first to use the term [*εἰδωλολατρία*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dei)dwlolatri%2Fa), e.g. Gal 5:20. (Corrections welcome!)

Two surprises come when we look at the Vulgate:

1. εἰδωλολατρία is translated as "idolorum servitus" (Gal 5:20) or "idolorum cultura" (1 Cor 10:14)
2. But: "idolatria" is used at least twice, to translate the Greek "κατείδωλον" (Acts 17:16) and "θεραφιν" (1 Sam 15:23, LXX) (which, I found out after some digging, is just a transliteration of Hebrew וּתְרָפִ֖ים (uterafim) = "household idol").

Although there are a *lot* of good questions that this cursory look bring up (many of which would probably find a better home at [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)), I will only ask one: **Why was εἰδωλολατρία transcribed as *idolatria* rather than *idololatria*?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The uncontracted "idololatria" is used by Tertullian, and by Jerome in his commentary on Isaiah (if we can trust the copyists and editors).

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Didololatria

"Idolatria" is common in Christian Latin (though it does not have an entry in L/S) and is continued by English “idolatry” and similar words in other modern languages. It is an example of haplology (as opposed to mere haplography).

Comment: I wonder if "haplogy" would be a more descriptive word than "haplology"... (+1 and apologies for the pun)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta You might have to issue a hapology for that. You are approaching the hapogee of inconsiderateness!

Comment: @fdb Great--"haplology" was the phenomenon I was looking for. Do you know how common this was for Greek->Latin words?

Comment: @brianpck. It is actually very rare. But see (Homer etc.) ἀμφιφορεύς > later ἀμφορεύς.

Comment: @brianpck. Another (Latin/Romance) example is late Latin carnelevare > Old Italian carnelevale (assimilation) > Tuscan carnevale (haplology) > English etc.  carnival. All the stages are really attested.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Vide _Studies out in Left Field: Defamatory essays presented to James D. McCawley on his 33rd or 34th birthday,_ [p. 125](https://books.google.com/books?id=JDDyZJWheHsC&pg=PA125&dq=haplogy). (My favorite is "haspiration".)